# sed command with five slashes

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Any idea what this is supposed to do?

```
grep -lr . | xargs sed -i '' -e '/ifcfg-wlan0/!s/wlan0/<name of the device>/g'
```

I've never seen a `sed` command with five slashes, and I can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: The part before the `s` command is a [regexp address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses)

Comment: [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+-lr+.+%7C+xargs+sed+-i+%27%27+-e+%27%2Fifcfg-wlan0%2F%21s%2Fwlan0%2F%3Cname+of+the+device%3E%2Fg%27) might be useful

Comment: @PabloA TIL about http://explainshell.com - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it as one command and one conditional. It means "replace all occurrences of `wlan0` with `<name of the device>` unless the line matches `ifcfg-wlan0`". Or, perhaps more accurately, it means "if this line matches `ifcfg-wlan0`, then don't replace `wlan0` with `<name of the device>`" so, by extension, do replace it on any lines that do not match `ifcfg-wlan0`.

This is one of many "addresses" that `sed` understands, specifically a regexp address, documented in `man sed` for my GNU `sed` as:

> /regexp/
>
> Match  lines  matching the regular expression regexp.  Matching is performed on the current pattern space, which can  be  modified with commands such as `s///`.

If you also know that `!` negates the next statement, you can then translate `/ifcfg-wlan0/!s/wlan0/<name of the device>/g'` into this pseudocode:

```
unless /ifcfg-wlan0/ {
   s/wlan0/<name of the device>/g
}
```

And, finally, here it is in action, with some whitespace added for clarity:

```
$ printf 'wlan0\nifcfg-wlan0\nwlan0\n'
wlan0
ifcfg-wlan0
wlan0

$ printf 'wlan0\nifcfg-wlan0\nwlan0\n' | 
    sed -e '/ifcfg-wlan0/ ! s/wlan0/<name of the device>/g'
<name of the device>
ifcfg-wlan0
<name of the device>
```